# Swift - execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_access multidimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, exc-bad-access

Learning to write swift code, looking at a multidimensional array, want to iterate through the array, withdraw the math function stored in the second column, and then add its first column value to 4 separate arrays (yet to be created) so at the end I will have 4 arrays, containing the number from the first column.

However on line

```
 Function = array3D[index]
```

I am getting error: swift execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_access

Can anyone help? Code below

```
var array3D: [[String]] = [["1", "+"], ["3", "-"], ["5", "x"], ["7", "/"]]
var arrayAdd = [""]
var arrayMinus = [""]
var arrayMultiple = [""]
var arrayDivide = [""]

var count = array3D.count
var countIsZero = false

if count != 0 {
    countIsZero = true
}

if countIsZero {
    for index in 0...count {
        var Function = ""
        Function = array3D[count][1]
        println(Function)
        switch Function {
            case "+": arrayAdd.append(array3D[count][0])
            case "-": arrayMinus.append(array3D[count][0])
            case "x": arrayMultiple.append(array3D[count][0])
            case "/": arrayDivide.append(array3D[count][0])
            default: ""
       }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` will be `4` because the array contains four elements. However, indexing is zero-based, so you should do:

```
for index in 0...count-1
```

to avoid indexing with the number `4` which would cause the exception.

Comment: @JamesWalker My pleasure. Good luck with the project.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but how do I declare an array as nothing to start? I want it to be a string, but I don't want there to be something in Line One which is just "", Otherwise I have to use arrayAdd.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

Comment: Using the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) it would be something like `var array3D = [[String]](count: 4, repeatedValue: ["", ""])`.

Answer (score 2):

What Klaus said is correct. Additionally:

- You'll want to ensure that each of your `case` statements doesn't go out of bounds by using `count`.
- You have the `for index in 0...count`statement, but I never see you using `index`, only `count`. `index` will be the number that counts up from 0.

Good luck,

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

`Function = array3D[4]` refers to  nothing <- throw `exc_bad_access`

Your array index go from `0` to `array3D.count - 1`

You need to change your for loop to the following: `0..<count` (same as `0...count-1`)

```
for index in 0..<count {
...
}
```

Also in your for loop you are using `count` instead of `index`:

Below the corrected loop:

```
for index in 0..<count {
    var Function = ""
    Function = array3D[index][1]
    println(Function)
    switch Function {
        case "+": arrayAdd.append(array3D[index ][0])
        case "-": arrayMinus.append(array3D[index ][0])
        case "x": arrayMultiple.append(array3D[index ][0])
        case "/": arrayDivide.append(array3D[index ][0])
        default: ""
    }
}
```